# How do I get SK sequences to run in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, sequence

I found this pretty useful code online but I'm having trouble getting it to run. The variable names are all correct and I've used print statements to make sure it does make it to this function. It just doesn't seem to run the sequence on the Label nodes. Thanks

```
func fadeOutInfoText(){

    infoLabel1.removeAllActions()
    infoLabel2.removeAllActions()
    speechIcon.removeAllActions()

    let wait:SKAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5)
    let fade:SKAction = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0, duration: 0.5)
    let run:SKAction = SKAction.run {

        self.infoLabel1.text = ""
        self.infoLabel2.text = ""
        self.infoLabel1.alpha = 1
        self.infoLabel2.alpha = 1
        self.speechIcon.alpha = 1
        self.speechIcon.isHidden = true
    }


    let seq:SKAction = SKAction.sequence([wait,fade,run])
    let seq2:SKAction = SKAction.sequence([wait,fade])

    infoLabel1.run(seq)
    infoLabel2.run(seq2)
    speechIcon.run(seq2)   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: This would be a comment (not enough reputation to do so yet :)

Executing the above code line-for-line (and adding in the nodes in an empty scene) gives what appears to be the desired result. Presumably you are not calling this function from the scene's `update(_:)` method, for this keeps the labels and speech icon from doing anything since the actions are removed before the scene performs the actions (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/responding_to_frame-cycle_events)). Make sure you aren't removing all actions and changing the alpha of the labels before this set of actions can complete elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code for Sequence.

```
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

    let scale = SKAction.scale(to: 0.1, duration: 0.5)
    let fade = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.5)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([scale, fade])

    sprite.run(sequence)
```

Let me know it is useful or not.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how the questioner should implement this.

Comment: I understand how it's supposed to work, it just doesn't for my example above. I've even tried doing this : 'infoLabel1.run(SKAction.sequence([ wait , fade , run ]))' to try and skip the seq line but it still didn't work. The label node is still showing the text instead of nothing. I also tried individual SKActions like the fade but still nothing.

Comment: So my suggestion is to have a local initialisation of SKSpriteNode and then run it.

Comment: I gave that a try but it's still not working. I tried using a different node with the sequence and that works so that makes me think it's something wrong with the Labels. I print the labels out at the start of the function and it does say what it's meant to so I can't see the problem it's having.